# SSRS Dynamic Borders

Tags: dynamic, reporting-services, settings

I have the following output which is bound to a SSRS table:

```
ID    Name            Value

1     Assets           100
2     Liabilities      200
3     Expenses         300
4     Loans            400
5     TOTAL           1000
```

For the last row (TOTAL), which is the grand total of the above rows, and also a part of the result, I want to set the border conditionally as follows:

- Top border: Dotted
- Bottom border: Double-dashed

The last row in the report must look something like this:

```
----------------
TOTAL   1000
================
```

Appreciate your inputs.

Comment: Do the bottom lines *have* to be double-dashed? SSRS does not have this option, only single-dashed. Would solid double lines work?

Comment: Yes, that must be fine, if there is no other option.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unfortunately, SSRS does not have a double-dashed option, but you can use conditional formatting on the textbox to control the border.

With your data:

[image]

I have a simple table:

[image]

For the detail row, I have set the Top and Bottom border style to be expression-based, based on the value of `Name`:

[image]

Top:

```
=IIf(Fields!Name.Value = "TOTAL", "Dashed", "None")
```

Bottom:

```
=IIf(Fields!Name.Value = "TOTAL", "Double", "None")
```

This gives (very close to) the desired result:

[image]

However, be aware that you might run into a few issues, as identified in this MSDN thread:

[Double Line border turn to be single in Reporting Service](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/f93cd843-001d-411a-8bf8-ee0799521604/double-line-border-turn-to-be-single-in-reporting-service)

I had to make sure the Bottom border was 3pt in width and that there was a table footer row to get it to look correct in Preview. Excel works fine whatever.